# Invalid Class Exception: No valid constructor

Tags: java, exception

This is odd, the class works fine until after logging out of the game but when logging back in it sends the exception.

Here's the child class

```
    package com.rs.game.player.quests.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.rs.game.player.Player;
import com.rs.game.player.dialogues.Dialogue;
import com.rs.game.player.quests.Quest;

/**
 * Handles the cooks assistant quest.
 * 
 * @author Thomas Le Godais <thomaslegodais@live.com>
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CooksAssistant extends Quest<CooksAssistant.Stage, CooksAssistant.Nodes> implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The current nodes of the quest.
     * 
     * @author Thomas Le Godais <thomaslegodais@live.com>
     *
     */
    public enum Nodes {
        /*
         * The chef node.
         */
        CHEF(false);


        /** The interaction value. **/
        private boolean value;

        /**
         * Constructs a new Nodes instance.
         * 
         * @param value the value.
         */
        private Nodes(boolean value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the node.
         * 
         * @return the value.
         */
        public boolean getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the node.
         * 
         * @param newValue the new value to set.
         */
        public void setValue(boolean newValue) {
            this.value = newValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The different stages of the quest.
     * 
     * @author Thomas Le Godais <thomaslegodais@live.com>
     *
     */
    public enum Stage {
        /*
         * Start the quest.
         */
        START,

        /*
         * Gather the ingredients.
         */
        GATHER_INGREDIENTS, 

        /*
         * The talk to chef.
         */
        TALK_TO_CHEF, 

        /*
         * Finish the quest.
         */
        FINISH

    }


    private Player player;

    /**
     * Constructs a new CooksAssistant instance.
     */
    public CooksAssistant(Player player) {
        super("Cooks' Assistant", 1, Stage.START, Nodes.CHEF);
        this.player = player;
    }


    @Override
    public void handleQuest() {
        switch(getQuestState()) {
        case START:
            player.getPackets().sendRunScript(1207, new Object[] { 5 });    
            player.getInterfaceManager().sendInterface(275);

            for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
                player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, i, "");

            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 1, this.getName());
            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 10, "Begin by speaking with the Cook in Lumbridge Castle.");

            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 12, "Requirments:");
            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 13, "<str>None.</str>");
            break;

        case GATHER_INGREDIENTS:
            player.getPackets().sendRunScript(1207, new Object[] { 5 });    
            player.getInterfaceManager().sendInterface(275);

            for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
                player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, i, "");

            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 1, this.getName());
            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 10, "You need the following requirements");

            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 12, "Requirments:");
            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 13, "Eggs");
            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 14, "Milk");
            player.getPackets().sendIComponentText(275, 15, "Flour");
            break;

        case TALK_TO_CHEF:

            break;

        case FINISH:

            break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void handleDialogue(int npcId) {
        switch(npcId) {
        case 847:
            player.getDialogueManager().startDialogue(new Dialogue() {

                private int npcId;

                @Override
                public void start() {                   
                    npcId = 847;

                    if(hasInteracted(Nodes.CHEF))
                        sendNPCDialogue(npcId, 9827, "Have you gathered my ingredients?.");
                    else
                        sendNPCDialogue(npcId, 9827, "Waahh, what am I to do? I'm so done for!!");
                }

                @Override
                public void run(int interfaceId, int componentId) {
                    if (!(hasInteracted(Nodes.CHEF))) {
                        switch (stage) {
                        case -1:
                            this.sendOptionsDialogue("What would you like?", new String[] { "What's wrong, chef?", "Grow up, you big baby!", "Nevermind, I'll leave you alone." });
                            stage = 0;
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            if (componentId == OPTION_1) {
                                sendPlayerDialogue(9827, "What's wrong, chef?");
                                stage = 1;
                            } else if (componentId == OPTION_2) {
                                sendPlayerDialogue(9827, "Grow up, you big baby!");
                                stage = 15;
                            } else if (componentId == OPTION_3) {
                                sendPlayerDialogue(9827, "Nevermind, I'll leave you alone.");
                                stage = 15;
                            }
                            break;
                            /*
                             * I need some ingredients for the kings birthday cake.
                             */
                        case 1:
                            sendNPCDialogue(npcId, 9827, "I need some ingredients for the kings birthday cake, and I do not have enough time to go get them myself.");
                            stage = 2;
                            break;
                            /*
                             * What do you need?
                             */
                        case 2:
                            sendPlayerDialogue(9827, "Well maybe I could be of assistance, what do you need?");
                            stage = 3;
                            break;
                            /*
                             * I need milk, eggs, and flour.
                             */
                        case 3:
                            sendNPCDialogue(npcId, 9827, "Well I have the frosting, so I guess that just leaves milk, eggs, and flour. Do you think you could help me out, there will be a small reward.");
                            stage = 4;
                            break;
                            /*
                             * That shouldn't be too hard to get.
                             */
                        case 4:
                            sendPlayerDialogue(9827, "That shouldn't be too hard for me to gather, I'll be back in a jiffy!");
                            stage = 5;
                            break;
                            /*
                             * Oh my god, that you so much.
                             */
                        case 5:
                            sendNPCDialogue(npcId, 9827, "Thank you so much, " + player.getUsername() + ", I owe you big time!");
                            setQuestState(Stage.GATHER_INGREDIENTS);
                            for(Nodes node : Nodes.values()) {
                                if(node.equals(Nodes.CHEF)) {
                                    node.setValue(true);
                                    stage = 15;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                            /*
                             * This is where we end the current dialogue.
                             */
                        case 15:
                            end();
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        switch(stage) {
                        case -1:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void finish() {                  
                }
            });
            break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void handleObjectClick(int objectId, boolean firstClick, boolean secondClick, boolean thirdClick) {      
        if(firstClick) {
            switch(objectId) {

            }
            return;
        } else if(secondClick) {
            switch(objectId) {

            }
            return;
        } else if(thirdClick) {
            switch(objectId) {

            }
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasDialogue() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasObjectClick() {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasInteracted(Nodes node) {
        if(node.getValue() == true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Here's the parent

```
    package com.rs.game.player.quests;

/**
 * Represents a single quest of the Rune-Force server.
 * 
 * @author Thomas Le Godais <thomaslegodais@live.com>
 * @param T
 *      An enumeration that is used to handle quest states.
 * @param E
 *      An enumeration that is used to handle interaction.
 */
public abstract class Quest<T extends Enum<T>, E extends Enum<E>> {

    /** The name of the quest. **/
    private String name;

    /** The id of the quest **/
    private int questId;

    /** The state of the quest to handle. **/
    private T questState;

    /** The node interaction. **/
    private E nodeInteraction;

    /**
     * Constructs a new AbstractQuest instance.
     * 
     * @param name The name of the quest.
     * @param questId The id of the quest.
     * @param questState The state of the quest.
     */
    public Quest(String name, int questId, T questState, E nodeInteraction) {
        this.name = name;
        this.questId = questId;
        this.questState = questState;
        this.nodeInteraction = nodeInteraction;
    }

    /**
     * Handles an quest.
     * 
     * @param player The player to handle the quest.
     */
    public abstract void handleQuest();

    /**
     * Handles the dialogue of the quest.
     * 
     * @param player the player interacting with the npc.
     * @param npcId the npc interacting with the player.
     */
    public abstract void handleDialogue(int npcId);

    /**
     * Handles object clicks.
     * 
     * @param player the player clicking objects.
     * @param objectId the object id.
     * @param firstClick the first click.
     * @param secondClick the second click.
     * @param thirdClick the third click.
     */
    public abstract void handleObjectClick(int objectId, boolean firstClick, boolean secondClick, boolean thirdClick);

    /**
     * Does the quest contain dialogue?
     * 
     * @return True, if it does.
     */
    public abstract boolean hasDialogue();

    /**
     * Does the quest contain object click?
     * 
     * @return True, if it does.
     */
    public abstract boolean hasObjectClick();

    /**
     * Checks if a player has interacted with a node.
     * 
     * @param node the node to interact.
     * @return has interacted or not.
     */
    public abstract boolean hasInteracted(E node);

    /**
     * Gets the current state of the quest.
     * 
     * @return The current state.
     */
    public T getQuestState() {
        return questState;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current state of the quest.
     * 
     * @param questState The state of the quest.
     */
    public void setQuestState(T questState) {
        this.questState = questState;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id of the quest.
     * 
     * @return The quest id.
     */
    public int getQuestId() {
        return questId;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of the quest.
     *
     * @return The name of the quest.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the node interaction.
     * 
     * @return the interaction.
     */
    public E getNodeInteraction() {
        return nodeInteraction;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the node interaction.
     * 
     * @param nodeInteraction the interaction to set.
     */
    public void setNodeInteraction(E nodeInteraction) {
        this.nodeInteraction = nodeInteraction;
    }
}
```

Here's the exception

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.rs.game.player.quests.impl.CooksAssistant; no valid constructor
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the contract for [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable.

`CooksAssistant` should have a no-args constructor for Serialization

```
public CooksAssistant() {
   super("Cooks' Assistant", 1, Stage.START, Nodes.CHEF);
}
```

As player is already a field it should be serialized correctly if set at the time of serialization

Comment: But its required in order for it to know what player is which is why I'm stuck right now ._.

Comment: See my last comment, i.e. if you just ensure that the player field is set during serialization then it _should_ already be set automatically during deserialization