# I get null pointer exception

Tags: java

I have three class as boat,car,truck etc who extend from vehicle , I write all the object of this in a file say vehicleOrder.dat like this :

```
fout = new FileOutputStream("VehicleOrders.dat");   
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout); 
oos.writeObject(v); //where v is object of boat,truck car etc
```

Till here its good ,it writes, but when I try to read the dat file like this,

```
fin = new FileInputStream("VehicleOrders.dat");
ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
vehicle readInstance=null;

do{
    readInstance = (vehicle)ois.readObject();
    if(readInstance != null)
    {
        orderList.add(readInstance);
    } 
}       
while (readInstance != null);
```

it reads the two objects which are in the dat file but after that goes to the do again and gives null pointer exception

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689814/invalid-class-exception-no-valid-constructor

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your class doesn't have 0-param-Constructor.
Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125076/java-deserialization-invalidclassexception-no-valid-constructor) will help you out about the explanation

Answer (score 0):

[`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) expects a visible no-arg constructor for the class instance you are trying to deserialize. I assume your class doesn't have one. Add one.

Comment: Yeah I search the net and found the same solution , now that excpetion is through but now I get Null pointer exception in the same line :(

Comment: @Snedden27 Which line is that? Please post a full stack trace by editing your question.

Comment: @Snedden27 You can edit your own question. Whatever post it here or just tell us exactly what the error is.